# What to do if my problem is already descibed in an other post, but the solution doesn't work for me?

Tags: support

I am having a problem that is fully described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/491274/server-cant-ping-or-connect-to-self), with only a small difference (the log of ifconfig that for me has a "lo" field). I could post an other question that would be nearly the same (same title, etc) but I guess it will be seen as a duplicate.

What is the best way to get an answer to my question ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the (Accepted or not) Answer offered in a existing similar Question doesn't apply, please post yours as a new question.

It is useful to show your research efforts in your own questions. Therefore please link to the question(s) your search found and confirm that although the symptoms are very similar you tried the suggested solution and found it didn't resolve your specific problem.

In general that will prevent the question from being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I was going to post my question but my problem has been solved at the same time, so there is no need to post it anymore. Thank you anyway!

Comment: +1 -  not to mention, linking both questions to show that quite similar symptoms can have different resolutions improves both questions